# Find k value to get the function pdf without integrating

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Find k value to get the function pdf

(b) $kx^2(4-x)^3$, for $0 < x < 4$. $0$ otherwise

Can this be done with gamma/beta distribution?

$$\int_{0}^{4} kx^2(4-x)^3dx$$

The definition is:

$$  
k\int_0^1 x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1} = k\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)} = B(\alpha,\beta)
$$

Doesn't work for $0$ to $4$

If I let $x = 4t$, then

$$\int_{0}^{4} 64t^2(4(1 - t))^3dt = \int_{0}^{4} 64t^24^3(1 - t)^3dt = 4096k \int_{0}^{4}t^2(1-t)^3dt$$

To be in beta form where $\alpha = 3$ and $\beta = 4$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using a change of variables $x\gets 4t$ works so

$$\int_0^4 k x^2(4-x)^3~\mathsf d x= \int_0^1 k(4t)^2(4-4t)^3\cdot 4\mathsf d t\\= 4^3k\int_0^1 t^2(1-t)^3~\mathsf d t$$

Comment: Now what: $4^5k\int_{0}^{1} t^2(1-t)^3 dt = \frac{T(3)T(4)}{T(7)} = \frac{2!4!}{6!} = k4^5/15, k = \frac{15}{4^5}$